# Multiple Expressions-Is find the right tool?

Tags: shell, unix, find

I have a good number of directories that contain the output and data files from a set of programs. Each directory has similar content and my go 4 more levels deep.  My goal is to identify all directories that have both core files in any subdirectory and log files of a given name pattern of size greater than 1k.  The log files won't be in the same subdir as the core file.

I can write find commands that work for each goal independently but all my attempts to combine the expressions fails to produce any results.

First command:

```
find \( \( -path "./SESS*" -name "log_snap_*" \) \( -size +1k\) \)
```

Second command:

```
find \( -path "./SESS" -regex "*core.[0-9]+\(.gz)*" \)
```

How can I write one test that identifies directories that meet both criteria?

Comment: Why all the nested groups? You just want the conditions ANDed, right?

Comment: For that matter, why `find -path ./SESS` and not `find ./SESS`? The latter is vastly more efficient, since it doesn't recurse down branches where you'll just regard every single result.

Comment: Also, `-regex "*core.[0-9]+\(.gz)*"` isn't actually a valid regex. You can't have `*` as the first character in a regular expression, since it means "zero-or-more of the preceding item"; at the first position, there **is** no preceding item.

Comment: Please see my answer for an idea of how the *question* should be structured -- showing code that creates a test environment, and then expected output given that test environment, and then actual output given that test environment. The [mcve] definition discusses this further.

Comment: ...if you provided such code -- doing the setup, and giving us the expected/intended output -- there would be no guessing or interpretation about your intended logic.

Comment: Many good comments and ideas here.   I will get rid of the -path and I had a typo, my regex did start with a '.'   My files look like this:
SESSION_1000
SESSION_1001
SESSION_1002
where there are several hundred session directories.  Each will have 6-8 subpaths that may go 4 levels deep.   I will try again without the groups but I truly want to AND all the conditions, not OR them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one reasonable interpretation of this question -- see below for an answer based on a different one.

---

#### Assuming You Mean "Either" Criteria...

Consider the following setup:

```
files_empty=(
  SESS/log_snap_1234  # ignored because not more than 1k in size
  SESS/ignoreme       # ignored because not matching either pattern 
  SESS/core.13.gz     # expected to be in results
  SESS/core.13        # expected to be in results
)
files_full=(
  SESS/log_snap_2345  # expected to be in results
)

{ tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/test.XXXXXX) && cd "$tempdir"; } || exit
mkdir -p SESS bad
touch "${files_empty[@]}"
for f in "${files_full[@]}"; do
  dd if=/dev/zero of="$f" bs=1k count=2
done
```

If, after using the above to create a test environment, we run the following in GNU `find`:

```
find ./SESS \
   '(' '(' -name 'log_snap_*' -size +1k ')' \
    -o '(' -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*core[.][0-9]+([.]gz)?" ')' \
   ')' -print
```

...we properly get the results:

```
./SESS/log_snap_2345
./SESS/core.13
./SESS/core.13.gz
```

---

So, what changed?

- Don't use `-path` to filter the locations being searched when you can just modify the starting locations instead. When you run `find . -path './SESS/*'`, that searches **everywhere** under `.`, but then throws away results whenever they don't match `./SESS/*`; that's extremely inefficient compared to only searching the directories you care about in the first place.
- Use `-o` to specify an OR condition.
- There's no point to grouping operators or an explicit `-a` when what you want is an AND between subsequent tests, since this is the implicit behavior.
- Specifying the final action (such as `-print`) explicitly is very good form. Not completely mandatory in your current situation, but it *is* mandatory in other common scenarios (such as when using `-prune`); making a habit thus reduces room for error.
- A regex is not permitted to start with a `*`, since `*` means "zero or more of the prior item". At the beginning of the regex, there *is* no prior item, so this construct has no meaning.
- Inside a regex, an explicit period should be written as `[.]`, since a bare `.` means "one of any character".

---

#### If You Really Mean "Both" Criteria...

We don't actually need to go into `find` for this part. One caveat: I'm knowingly avoiding correctly handling the case where filenames contain literal newlines. This can happen. Ignoring it isn't ideal.

Anyhow, take the two shell functions as stand-ins for the output of two different `find` commands:

```
find1_cmd() {
  printf '%s\n' \
    SESS/session_one/log_snap_1234 \
    SESS/session_one/log_snap_4567 \
    SESS/session_three/log_snap_8901
}

find2_cmd() {
  printf '%s\n' \
    SESS/session_one/core.1234.gz
    SESS/session_four/core.5678.gz
}
```

We can find only the directories present in both, as follows:

```
prep() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line%/*}"  # remove the filename, leaving only the directory
  done | sort -u                # sort and uniq-ify the results
}

comm -12 <(find1_cmd | prep) <(find2_cmd | prep)
```

You could of course replace the `while` loop with any other means of stripping off the filename and leaving only the directory. The important thing is that we're (1) generating a sorted list of unique directories found by each command; and (2) using `comm` to exclude directories unique to one or the other.

See [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) for more on using `comm`.

Comment: Yes, I do want the AND of all criteria, not an OR.  I want to identify top level SESSION_xxxx directories that have core files and some log file of a certain size.